# How to upload multiple images in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to upload multiple images using image model not like a nested serializer
Here is my serializer

```py
class ProjectImageSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProjectImage
        fields = (
            'id',
            'file',
            'project',
        )
```

This is the model

```
class ProjectImage(models.Model):
    file = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='apps/projects/ProjectImage/file/',
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        'users.User',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='project_image_set',
    )
    project = models.ForeignKey(
        'Project',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='image_set',
    )
    created = CreatedField()
    last_modified = LastModifiedField()

    def __str__(self):
        return basename(self.file.name)
```

and here is Views.py

```
class ProjectImageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    parser_classes = [
        MultiPartParser,
    ]
    queryset = ProjectImage.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProjectImageSerializer
```

can anyone help me when I try with postman its selecting multiple images but posting only one

Answer (score 1):

You can't use this serializer for uploading multiple images. You should define another serializer which accepts a list of files in one of the fields. Something like this:

```
class UploadSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    images = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.ImageField())
```

And then implement your logic to create `ProjectImage` instances in the create method.

Comment: so you mean nested serializer?

Comment: No this is not a nested serializer. Look at the code I sent you. To test whether it works, you can use postman and select multiple files for the field 'images'

Comment: I'm just giving you the idea. You can also modify the `ProjectImageSerializer` you wrote and add this field.

Comment: `class UploadSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    file = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.ImageField())


class ProjectImageSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    file = UploadSerializer()
`I changes the model like this now it gives me null values

Comment: In create method ```    def create(self, validated_data):
        image_data = validated_data.pop('file')
        user_obj = ProjectImage.objects.create(
            **validated_data,
            user=self.context['request'].user,
        )
        for image_data in image_data:
            ProjectImage.objects.create(
                **image_data,
                user_obj=user_obj
            )
        return user_obj```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ProjectImageSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProjectImage
        fields = (
            'id',
            'file',
            'project',
        )
        read_only_fields = ['id']
        extra_kwargs = {'file': {'required': 'True'}}
```

Try above code

Comment: ```TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'multiple'```got an error

Comment: I have removed that multiple = true

Comment: try without multiple

Comment: please provide your main project urls.py file and setting file

Comment: then it still upload single file/ single image I want to upload multiple images

Comment: there is some logic which needs to be added in serializers.py file in create method but can't figure out